# Inconsistent Go error return using if-construction with cypher/aes

Tags: if-statement, encryption, go, error-handling, aes

I'm seeing strange behaviour where I should get an error back from a function, but I get nil instead.

The following code block contains 2 encrypt functions using cypher/aes. The only difference is the first 1/2 lines of each function. In `encrypt2`, I've combined the assignment of the first line of `encrypt1` into the conditional.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    invalidKey := []byte("TCbKgXZsT")
    plaintext := []byte("dummycontenttoenctrypt")
    fmt.Println(encrypt1(plaintext, invalidKey))
    fmt.Println(encrypt2(plaintext, invalidKey))
}

func encrypt1(plaintext []byte, key []byte) (encrypted []byte, err error) {
    c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err == nil {
        if gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(c); err == nil {
            nonce := make([]byte, gcm.NonceSize())
            if _, err = io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, nonce); err == nil {
                return gcm.Seal(nonce, nonce, plaintext, nil), nil
            }
        }
    }
    return nil, err
}

func encrypt2(plaintext []byte, key []byte) (encrypted []byte, err error) {
    if c, err := aes.NewCipher(key); err == nil {
        if gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(c); err == nil {
            nonce := make([]byte, gcm.NonceSize())
            if _, err = io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, nonce); err == nil {
                return gcm.Seal(nonce, nonce, plaintext, nil), nil
            }
        }
    }
    return nil, err
}
```

[Go Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/kBpEwOU75_)

I expected the same behaviour from these functions, as the logic is the same. However, calling `encrypt1` returns an error (correct), while `encrypt2` does not return the error (returns just nil).

I have used named arguments, so `err` is declared at the start of the function and should be populated by the first error in both functions.

Anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Here's a simplified version of what's going on: https://play.golang.org/p/LmTQB9qfGz it has nothing to do with crypto, aes and error handling. In general, don't use named returns unless you actually plan to use them (which your code doesn't). Remove the named returns and you'll immediately see what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to do with scoping rules, here is a simplified example:

https://play.golang.org/p/1dCaUB948p

```
func encrypt2(plaintext []byte, key []byte) (encrypted []byte, err error) {
    if _, err := returnErr(); err == nil {
        fmt.Println("inner loop")
    }
    return nil, err
}
```

If you remove the named arguments, it won't compile, which gives a hint of the problem - the err declared in your if statement does not affect the outer scope, it is only valid within the if statement. If you remove the := assignment, you'll see what you expect.

In go a more verbose version which returns on error is usually preferred, rather than lots of nested if statements, so that you can return specific errors and the flow of logic is clear. It's easy if nesting to forget scope or which variables are assigned when, whereas if you adopt this [return on error](https://medium.com/@matryer/line-of-sight-in-code-186dd7cdea88) style the reader knows at any given point no errors have been encountered. You don't have to annotate errors where the original error is self-evident of course, you could just return nil,err.

```
func encrypt3(plaintext []byte, key []byte) ([]byte, error) {

    c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("encrypt: invalid key :%s", err)
    }

    gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(c)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("encrypt: error creating cipher :%s", err)
    }

    nonce := make([]byte, gcm.NonceSize())
    _, err = io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, nonce)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("encrypt: error creating nonce :%s", err)
    }

    return gcm.Seal(nonce, nonce, plaintext, nil), nil
}
```

If you're doing aes encryption in Go, a good ref is this [code](https://github.com/gtank/cryptopasta/blob/master/encrypt.go) and [video](https://golangnews.com/stories/1469-video-crypto-for-go-developers-gophercon-crypto) by George Tankersley.